# Questions about regular expression matching results

Tags: regular-expression

I executed the following command

```
ip addr | grep -En 'inet (([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*)/24' | awk '{print "LAN:" $3 }'
```

why the result is '192.168.123.245/24', instead of this`192.168.123.245`?

Another problem is that **I must use $3** to print ip instead of `$1`.

Comment: Why would it be `192.168.123.245`? Your pattern explicitly includes it (and you're printing the whole line anyway) and awk doesn't split on `/` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run you command without the `awk`part and you will see what there is `$3` needed.

```
ip addr | grep -En 'inet (([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*)/24'
```

The command without `awk` will give you something like this.

```
11:    inet 192.168.1.26/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
21:    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
```

You can see that first column is line number `11:` and `21:`. Then there is `inet`, and the third column is the ip number with mask. No matter what you do with grep the ip number will always have the netmask attached. If you want to get rid of netmask you should use `sed` or something that will also change your found lines. Grep will only display what it finds.

Try this:

```
ip addr | grep -En 'inet (([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/24' | awk '{print "LAN:" $3 }' | sed -En 's/(LAN:.*)\/24/\1/p'
```

I am sure it can be done more elegantly.

Comment: Thank you! Referring to your comment, it maybe more elegantly  `ip addr | sed -En 's/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*)\/24/\2/p' | awk '{ print "LAN:" $1 }'`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
ip addr | grep 'inet.*\/24' | grep -oE '(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*)' | awk '{ print "LAN:"$1 }'
```

First grep catches lines with /24 networks. The next one matches IPv4 addresses, the `-o` arg tells grep to print only matched part of string. And awk substitutes "LAN:" at the beginning of string.

Now about why your snippet works as you asked. Without `-o` key grep prints the whole string with match, then awk prints third "argument", i.e. a third "word" separated with whitespaces.